# in pfsense, its possible to secure the conf.cf (primary configuration file)

Tags: security, pfsense, encryption

I want to give someone a solution based on embedded pfSense. That solution has modifications in pfSense, which I don't want anyone to steal and use it for their own  business. its proprietary solution that i built to provide services based on pfSense.
Can i somehow encrypt/secure the contents/data of pfSense? or may be just conf.cf file?

- I tried to encrypt whole disk, using pfSense Full Disk Encryption, but as the device will be with end user, he cannot always give password at each boot time
- May be encrypt /cf/conf.cf folder? (so no one can copy it)

What other options are there to secure that data in the pfSense? to secure its contents and data from stealing?

Comment: Does your client own the device, or do you provide it as part of a managed service?